# SQL DateDiff Syntax

Tags: sql, database, syntax

I have a homework problem that I'm having a lot of trouble with... I don't expect the answer and I truly want to learn it. Could somebody help me out with the syntax?

Problem:
For each Sales Order, show how many days it took to ship the order in order by the longest order, then by Sales Order Number. Display Sales Order Number and the number of days to ship. Include the orders that have not yet shipped.

So far I have:

```
SELECT SalesOrder.SalesOrderNumber, 
DATEDIFF (d, MIN(SalesOrder.OrderDate), MAX(Shipment.ShipmentDate)) AS "DaysToShip"
FROM SalesOrder, Shipment
GROUP BY SalesOrder.SalesOrderNumber;
```

Comment: You are missing join conditions.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I thank you for answering.

Comment: @JaseMcLeod You need to include a condition that relates rows in `SalesOrder` to rows in `Shipment`.  Something like `FROM SalesOrder JOIN Shipment ON SalesOrder.SalesOrderNumber = Shipment.SalesOrderNumber`, but substitute the correct relating column names.

Comment: `DATEDIFF()` is not universally supported, so suggest you add tag for your `RDBMA` -- Access, SQL Server, MySQL, or what?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it's helpful to see an intermediate form of your query to evaluate if it's providing the correct data at some stage.

Consider the following query, pulled from your example minus some elements:

```
SELECT SalesOrder.SalesOrderNumber, SalesOrder.OrderDate, Shipment.ShipmentDate
FROM SalesOrder, Shipment
```

You should observe the results of this query and see how they differ from what you expect. In this case, you haven't indicated how `SalesOrder` and `Shipment` are related. The result will be many more rows than there are orders, with each `SalesOrder` related to each and every other Shipment record (a cross-join).

Once you provide the correct join condition and achieve the desired results at that stage, try adding in aggregation (`GROUP BY`, `MIN`, `MAX`) and test that form of your query.  Finally, when you're convinced that you have the correct inputs, add in `DATEDIFF` and you'll have your final query.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT SalesOrder.SalesOrderNumber, 
    DATEDIFF (d, MAX(SalesOrder.OrderDate), MAX(Shipment.ShipmentDate)) AS "DaysToShip"
FROM SalesOrder, Shipment
GROUP BY SalesOrder.SalesOrderNumber;
```